# shell script: Syntax error

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run a shell script.

The first two lines are like follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
gr = (file1 file2 file3)
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:
fileName.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

I am not used to writing this type of scripts, but I read that the parentheses are used for grouping...

I don't understand what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this to make an array :

```
gr=(file1 file2 file3)
```

No spaces allowed in variable assignation in all kinds.

Comment: @bigTree Make sure you're running `bash`. Try `bash script.sh` instead of just running it with `sh script.sh` or `./script.sh`.

Comment: @konsolebox My bad, now it works thanks! could you tell me what the difference is please? (thanks!)

Comment: @bigTree: The `#!/bin/bash` tells the system to use `/bin/bash` to execute the script -- but only if you execute it directly by typing its name. If you type `sh script-name`, you're feeding the script to `sh`. The whole point of the `#!` line is that you don't have to do that; you can treat the script as an executable file without having to care (as a user) how it's executed.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your program and I got the same error.

```
[admin@hp ~]$ sh fileName.sh 
fileName.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
fileName.sh: line 2: `gr = (file1 file2 file3)'
```

I just change the program like this:

```
[admin@hp ~]$ cat fileName.sh 
#!/bin/bash
gr=(file1 file2 file3)
```

And the problem disappear.

```
[admin@hp ~]$ vi fileName.sh
```